# UnSync Quote from Opportunity When Field changes using PB

Tags: process-builder, quote

Trying to use a PB. Very simple, if Field A changes opportunity, UnSync Quote by Setting SyncedQuoteId = Globalconstant.null.

However, I'm only able to do this from a PB based on Quote Object fields directly i.e. if quote status changes, it will unsync, but if Opp Field A changes unsync does not occur.

Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying it from a third object, to determine which of the following is true:

- Only quotes can unsync themselves from opportunities
- Only opportunities prevent unsyncing from quotes

It may be that the issue is on the opportunity object itself. My company has a fairly complex org, and as a result there are a decent amount of problems that come from one workflow rule, PB, managed package trigger etc. undoing the work of another.

For example, we use Queueables pretty heavily, and when triggering queueables to run, we've learned to only pass ids to the queueable, instead of entire SObject records. Passing ids forces the queueable author to requery any related records, instead of reusing records that came from another transaction.

This is important because we've seen situations where a checkbox is true when the queueable is launched, then later a PB (correctly) unchecks it, then when the queueable runs, it updates the record to handle an unrelated change, but includes the (incorrect) *original value of true* in the save operation.

All of that to say, if you have multiple configurations or managed packages involved with an update, values can get cached, and an update that succeeded might be reverted, like the SyncedQuoteId. So first I'd say you should prove out which object is special: the quote or the opportunity. Then if it's the opportunity, try to do the unsync logic in an empty scratch org or developer org containing none of your customizations. If it's still a problem there, then Salesforce is probably being magical again.

Comment: Thanks Nathanael. I am in a similar situation, however, I have looked through all workflows, all process builders, and apex code to determine where the SyncedQuoteId is being Set, and there aren't any additional processes, that are in our codebase that can be seen.

Comment: Trying a third object will not necessarily help because the field "Syncing" on the quote is directly tied to the SyncedQuoteId field on the Opportunity. The challenge seems to be that the syncedQuote package is running some code int he background that is rechecking the box on opportunity updates. For example, in order to see a field change on the opp from the quote, I would need to have a linked quote, but if I unlink the quote then it seems that other processes that update the opp fail and so they reset the synced quote after I have unsynced it.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'd suggest doing it in a completely new org, with zero customizations. If it's still an issue there, then you've proven it's the nature of the SyncedQuote functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It was discovered that this is related to a managed package from Force Labs. There is unpredictable behavior with updating the quote from the Process Builder.

Mainly, that if you update an Opportunity's `SyncedQuoteId` on a change, the field can be set to `null` however, the Quote.isSyncing field stays true and is presented this way int eh UI on the quote and Opp as well.

If more information is needed, I can reproduce and provide screen shots on request. But this appears to be a bug with the application.

**Solution**

The route that we went was creating a Path field on the quote for Unsynced. When a field changes on the Opportunity we move the quote to Unsynced, but do not actually unsync the qoute.

From the quote side, we found a custom setting in the Managed package, where we were able to set the values of fields on the quote with the API name of the field on the Opp and the API name of the corresponding field on the Quote. If a field on the quote is updated that is located in the custom setting, the managed package will automatically unsync the qoute. So we are making our quote fields read-only to users with more restricted permissions to prevent unSyncing.

Finally, to get the user interface to update, we actually revert back in the Process Builder when a field changes to the initial stage on the quote. This provides us with a fresh view of opp and quote data.